# Using SqlPackage to Extract DB results in "Login failed for user "someUser""

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlpackage

I am new to using SqlPackage.

I have a powershell command that looks something like

```
.\SqlPackage.exe /TargetFile:"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DAC\bin\\somefile.bacpac" /Action:extract /SourceServerName:"someServer" /SourceDatabaseName:"someDB" /SourceUser:"someUser" /SourcePassword:"somePassword" /DiagnosticsFile:"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DAC\\bin\\extract-log"
```

When I run this command I get the error

```
*** Error extracting database:Could not connect to database server.
Login failed for user "someUser"
```

I have checked the username and password and they are both correct. I used them to successfully login to SSMS. The user is the admistrator on the server, so should not be an issue with permissions I don't think.

I have followed the instructions to view the logs but under the server I do not have a Management tab. I do not understand why since I am the admin on the server.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can find the source of the issue?

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs for the *real* authentication error. If you don't understand that, then [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: *"I do not have a Management tab"* then I would suggest speaking to your DBA; they will be able to help you debug the problem.

Comment: I am logged in use the administrator account for the server. It does not make much sense why the admi account would not have the proper permissions. Simply telling me to go talk to someone else does not help much.

Comment: *"I am logged in use the administrator account for the server."* An administrator on the host does not make you an administrator on the instance. The permissions on the instance are completely separate. *"Simply telling me to go talk to someone else does not help "* Then provide us with the true authentication error. Otherwise the reasons could be one of many, and if you don't have administrative access to the instance, it is unlikely you'll be resolve many of them unless you have the incorrect login details for the `LOGIN`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error could be one of many. Without the true authentication error, from the SQL Server logs, it's impossible to state what the solution is, but here are a few possible reasons:

- The Connection details are incorrect.

  - You are using the wrong `LOGIN` and/or password combination. Check that the creditials are correct against those stored in your password management software.
  - You are connecting to the wrong instance, and the `LOGIN` does not exist on the instance. Check that the instance details in your connection string are correct.
- The `LOGIN` you are using is disabled. You need to log onto the server and re-enable it:

  ```sql
  ALTER LOGIN someUser ENABLE;
  ```
- The `LOGIN` doesn't have the connect permission. YOu need to log onto the server and `GRANT` it:

  ```sql
  GRANT CONNECT SQL TO SomeUser
  ```
- The `LOGIN` is trying to connect to a database it does not have a mapped `USER` on. You will need to `CREATE` the `USER` objects in the database(s) it requires access to, along with granting those `USER`s the needed permissions. You would create the `USER` with:

  ```sql
  USE YourDatabase;
  GO
  CREATE USER SomeUser FOR LOGIN SomeUser;
  ```
- There is a server trigger causing an error. Check that there are no triggers that are misbehaving that would cause the authentication to fail.
- Another reason that would be exposed in the SQL Server log.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if you are driving sqlpackage.exe using a batch file (as you might do when attempting to extract a DB with validation=False so you can actually work on it) and the account password contains a % character.
I haven't tested exhaustively and other special characters may cause issues with powershell etc.